# scp file from machine A to machine with no password prompt and copy same file to different location

Tags: linux, scp

I am trying to write a shell script through which i want to copy file from machineA to machine B.I have already setup passwordless connection .In the machine B again the samefile i want to copy to different path in the which 
 the directory is owned by different user. How can I achive this

Example:

1. Machine A

   ```
   scp /home/user/txt user@xhost/home/user/txt
   ```
2. Machine B

   It simply copies the file without asking password under home directory

   ```
   machineB:/home/user/
   ```

   I again want to copy the same file into diffrent location i get permission denied:

   ```
   cp /home/user/txt /apps/java/software/    # (permission denied)
   ```

Comment: You've got two requirements: (a) `scp` the file to a target, (b) execute a command as a different user on that target. Both parts are answered (separately) here on [Unix.SE].

Answer (score 0):

When you copy "the same file" to a different location, you need to `scp` with a user account which has access to the file AND the location you're copying it to. Without such permissions you'll get permission denied.